# A question about how to use the convexity condition?

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, regularity

At page 5 (125), seven line after the Proof of Theorem 2.2(i), of the following article.

[THE HEAT EQUATION WITH A SINGULAR POTENTIAL](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1984-284-01/S0002-9947-1984-0742415-3/S0002-9947-1984-0742415-3.pdf)

the authors say that since $p$ is convex, we can deduce that

$$ \int_{\delta}^{t} \int_{\Omega} p(u_n) (- \Delta \phi) \leq \int_{\delta}^{t} \int_{\Omega} \nabla u_n \cdot \nabla (\phi \, p'(u_n)). $$

I am confused about how convexity is used. I will be thanked if anyone could help me.

Comment: If $\phi$ is a positive cutoff, then after integrating by parts on the left side (in space) we get the right side, minus an integral of positive quantities times $p''(u_n)$.

Comment: @Connor Mooney: Thanks